# TortoiseSVN - How to update branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i create a branches/test form trunk

Then i work on trunk, so trunk is newly than branches/test

How to update branches with new changed in trunk ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge from trunk to branch.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to read the [Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  It's got a fine section on branching and merging.

Answer (score 0):

That is called merge, Check TotoiseSVN menu option called **Merge**. You could find that menu when you right click on the branch checked out folder.

Comment: oh my god, i only do merge form branches to trunk . thank you very much